# How is it possible in Python we use methods as variables?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, methods

```
    n=int(input())
    a=list(map(int,input().split()))
    sum=a[0]
```

How is "sum" a method used as a variable in the above code?

Comment: You are overwriting the definition of `sum`. If you then tried to use it as a function e.g. `sum(a)` you would get an error: "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python has a hierarchy of namespaces that it will use to resolve a name. In a function it is locals, globals, then builtins. At the module level its just globals then builtins. You can assign any legal variable name to globals, including any name in the builtins. "sum" in globals shadows the builtin name. It would be expensive to test every global variable assignment against the names in `builtins` and also not desirable - as stands you can purposely override any of the builtin functions if you care to do so.

When the script runs, "sum" is not in globals and so it resolves to the builtin function.

```
>>> "sum" in globals()
False
>>> sum
<built-in function sum>
>>> id(sum)
139891628989872
```

Assign something and now its in globals, shadowing the function.

```
>>> sum = "foo"
>>> sum
'foo'
>>> "sum" in globals()
True
```

Remove it from globals and you get the previously shadowed function again.

```
>>> del sum
>>> sum
<built-in function sum>
>>> id(sum)
139891628989872
```